# Random Color-Combinations (Text/Background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have 15 divs with text-elements and want following:

On every pageload the div-background-color AND the text-element-color should change into a randomly chosen color-combination.

I have 10 text-&-background-color-combinations:
combination-1: text blue / background-color cyan
combination-2: text yellow / background-color pink
combination-3: text cyan / background-color red
combination-4: text red / background-color blue
etc.

Now I want that a jQuery script randomly give the color-combinations to the divs (the text-color and div-background-color).

Please consider, I don't want just random colors but random color-combinations (random color-pairs).

Could you help me somehow?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var back = ["#ff0000","blue","gray", "red", "green", "white"];
    var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    console.log(rand);
    $('div').css('background',rand);
    $('span').css('color',rand);
    })
```

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>text</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJTHc/356/
(text and background are always the same random color)

I have no idea how to solve this combination-thing…

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sJTHc/356/ (text and background are always the same random color)

Comment: You're using the same number. Generate a different random number for the other color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var colors = [
    ['blue', 'cyan'],
    ['yellow', 'pink'],
    // etc…
];

function getRandomColorCombination(colors) {
    var random = parseInt(Math.random() * colors.length);

    return colors[random];
}

$('div').each(function () {
    var randomColorCombination = getRandomColorCombination(colors);

    $(this).css('color', randomColorCombination[0]);
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', randomColorCombination[1]);
});
```